# I do not understand the feedback about my title

Tags: support, specific-question, site-policy, titles

I don't understand how my question does not fit the site's standards. Can I please get some guidance?

[Is this an appropriate use of async/await combined with Task continuation?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/250002/is-this-an-appropriate-use-of-async-await-combined-with-task-continuation?noredirect=1#comment490472_250002)

> The current question title of your question is too generic to be helpful. Please edit to the site standard, which is for the title to simply **state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).
> – [BCdotWEB](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/10582/bcdotweb)
> [2020-09-30 07:45:06Z, License: CC BY-SA 4.0](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/250002/42401#comment490377_250002)

> @BCdotWEB: I checked meta -- sanity check questions were allowed with sufficient code
> – [Bryan Boettcher](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/6627/bryan-boettcher)
> [2020-09-30 14:33:59Z, License: CC BY-SA 4.0](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/250002/42401#comment490412_250002)

> @BryanBoettcher It is not about this question being allowed, it is about this question having a bad title. Please read my comment and follow the link, and update the question to this site's standards,.
> – [BCdotWEB](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/10582/bcdotweb)
> [2020-09-30 16:13:06Z, License: CC BY-SA 4.0](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/250002/42401#comment490420_250002)

> Is it the "Is this an appropriate use" qualifier that you take issue with, @BCdotWEB?
> – [Bryan Boettcher](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/6627/bryan-boettcher)
> [2020-09-30 19:19:09Z, License: CC BY-SA 4.0](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/250002/42401#comment490433_250002)

> @BryanBoettcher I repeat: please read my comment, follow the link and read the instructions, and update the question to this site's standards,
> – [BCdotWEB](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/10582/bcdotweb)
> [2020-10-01 06:47:43Z, License: CC BY-SA 4.0](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/250002/42401#comment490472_250002)

> @BCdotWEB can we discuss it in meta? [codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10555/…](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10555/what-about-bcdotwebs-feedback-am-i-not-understanding)
> – [Bryan Boettcher](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/6627/bryan-boettcher)
> [2020-10-01 15:29:22Z, License: CC BY-SA 4.0](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/250002/42401#comment490517_250002)

Answer (score 6):

Your title doesn't match the site's standard.

> Is this an appropriate use of async/await combined with Task continuation?

The title is *what you want out of the review* however pretty much all Code Review questions would be titled the same as yours and is generally not great. As such you should change the title to what your code does.

There is additional information in the [in the help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) that BCdotWEB linked to.

> ## Titling your question
>
> State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it. Be descriptive and interesting, and you'll attract more views to your question.
>
> Here are some examples of titles that are unacceptable because they are too generic:
>
> - How can I make this faster? (Everyone prefers faster code. The (performance) tag can convey this desire.)
> - Simplify this chain of if statements (Applies to too many questions.)
> - Ruby function needs refactoring (Reviewers will decide if it needs refactoring. You don't have to ask for it in the title.)
> - Is this good OOP design? (Title is not distinctive.)
> - Online judge says Time Limit Exceeded (Title tells us nothing beyond what would be conveyed by (programming-challenge) and (time-limit-exceeded) tags.)
>
> Furthermore, you should omit these kinds of superfluous phrases from titles, because these requests are implicit in every Code Review question:
>
> - Can you critique my …
> - Please help me…
> - … needs improvement
> - Reduce the complexity of…
>
> The norm is to summarize the goal of the code in the title. Some typical titles are:
>
> - Project Euler 9: finding a Pythagorean triplet
> - Game of Life with a Swing UI
> - View controller for smoking cessation iOS app
> - Validating inputs for a vacation request form
>
> If your code does not have a goal, then it is likely that your question contains hypothetical code, or that you are asking about best practices in general rather than for a review of your code. Such questions are off-topic for Code Review.

Comment: Would a better title be "async/await with Task Continuations"?

Comment: @BryanBoettcher Possibly "Asynchronous Task Continuations" would be better. However I have not read your question to the extent to be able to provide a good alternate.

Comment: The concern I'm trying to get reviewed is whether it is appropriate to blend both async/await keywords with Task Continuation -- perhaps "Will there be runtime problems mixing async/await and Task continuations?"

Comment: @BryanBoettcher No. That title would be describing what you want out of a review not what your code is / does.